# Http 404 when trying to get files with special characters from GitLab API

Tags: python-2.7, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am using python-gitlab driver for the Gitlab API. The following work fine on my repository:

```
>>> rf_blob = p.repository_blob(p_latest_commit.id, 'iOSBoilerplate/GooglePlus/GoogleOpenSource.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GTMOAuth2Authentication.h')
>>> rf_blob = p.repository_blob(p_latest_commit.id, 'iOSBoilerplate/GooglePlus/GoogleOpenSource.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GTMOAuth2SignIn.h')
```

However, when I try to open a file that contains a `+` character in it, I get the following even though that file clearly exists in the repository:

```
>>> rf_blob = p.repository_blob(p_latest_commit.id, 'iOSBoilerplate/GooglePlus/GoogleOpenSource.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GTMNSString+URLArguments.h')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitlab/objects.py", line 1521, in repository_blob
    raise_error_from_response(r, GitlabGetError)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitlab/exceptions.py", line 140, in raise_error_from_response
    response_body=response.content)
gitlab.exceptions.GitlabGetError: 404: 404 File Not Found
```

How exactly do I go about escaping the `+` in python so that I can get the blob of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `urllib.quote`.

python-gitlab is a superficial wrapper upon the real Gitlab API. The Gitlab API functions on url requests so this solution seemed natural:

```
rf_blob = p.repository_blob(p_latest_commit.id, urllib.quote('iOSBoilerplate/GooglePlus/GoogleOpenSource.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GTMNSString+URLArguments.h'))
```